# Iterate over lines in std::string without copying it

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a large string which can be 50-200 MB. I want to iterate over the lines in the string. Most of the solutions I searched use [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) and some of them required Boost library. I am not using them because, for example, they require me to copy the string to create a stringstream.

Do I really need to use them? Why should I not simply use `std::string`'s `find` to search for `\n` and read sub-strings? Is it a bad solution?

Comment: Which version of C++ are you using? Please update the tags too.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: `Do I really need to use them?` No. `Why should I not simply` No reason, do it. `Is it a bad solution?` No.

Comment: Btw beware big contiguous arrays of data, sometimes it's better and more handy to have a vector of smaller chunks, parts of which are cheap to copy (or to just inefficiently handle)

Comment: Updated tags. I was a bit suspicious of people always suggesting to use `std::getline` and not just  `std::string`'s `find` for some reason in a loop. Can I make string's in-built `find` to work on any whitespace characters like `std::getline` e.g. find `\n` or `\r\n`?. Yes, sorry. I mean `std::string`'s `find` function (not really `std::find`).

Comment: [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)

Comment: @user963241: I think you might be looking for `find_first_of`. You can then pass a list of whitespace characters.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes. That's what I was looking it. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you do not need to use `std::getline` or Boost.
2. Yes, you could use `string.find()`. Or, you could read the string from its source and build a list of substrings as you find the separators.
3. No, if it gets you to your answer then that is fine. It is not a bad solution unless you have specific performance requirements, RAM limitations or other requirements you have not mentioned.

Also, you can use [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) in C++17. Therefore, you can put your entire input into one string then create cheap substring objects that reference the original string.

Comment: The `string_view` seems even more promising to avoid copying. I'll see how it works.